# Nested select statement with HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, subquery

I want to join table Project with table ProjectPage based on distinct ids from ProjectPage the two tables, i'm using `HQL` and i tried the following:

```
EntityManager em = entityManager();
TypedQuery<Project> q = em.createQuery("SELECT o FROM Project AS o inner join
      (SELECT DISTINCT  pp.id  from ProjectPage) pp" +
      "on o.id=pp.id WHERE LOWER(o.name) LIKE LOWER(:name) "+
      "and ( o.status is null or o.status != :status_val)", Project.class);
```

i got the following error:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter : unexpected token: (
```

what's the problem in my query?

Comment: Try: `"SELECT o FROM Project AS o inner join
      (SELECT DISTINCT  pp.id  from ProjectPage pp) ppid " +
      "on o.id=ppid WHERE LOWER(o.name) LIKE LOWER(:name) "+
      "and ( o.status is null or o.status != :status_val)`
You missed the alias for ProjectPage on the inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Table alias in the select statement perhaps?

```
SELECT o FROM Project AS o
```

Did you mean

```
SELECT o.* FROM Projects AS o
```